# Has anyone figured out how to "Shareplay via Airdrop"?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wwdc, shareplay

I would like to add a functionality to my app similar to this WWDC video:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10239/
(6:42)

I've already implemented a GroupActivity via a FaceTime call similar to the "Draw Together" app example but I couldn't find any information about how to "bump" two devices to start a GroupActivity via Airdrop.

Has anyone of you figured out a way to this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Open the app that you have supported the SharePlay with, and then try bumping it with another device. This works with Music app, but when tried with my own application, it was completely buggy and the session did not start as it would start with Facetime. This is the behaviour observered at the time of RC release of iOS17. Have to wait for this to work properly.